# GROUP BY Category and ORDER Categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this simple example below. I want to make a select statement
that displays all the records, gouped by each distinct Category (ascending), and members of each category group should be ordered alphabetically by Fruit name:

```
ID        Fruit        Category
_________________________________________
1          Apple        200  
2          Pear         200
3          Banana       300
4          Peach        300
5          Mango        300
6          Tomato       600
7          Cucomber     600
8          Jackfruit    300
9          Salad        600 
10         Cranberries  200
```

I can't figure out how to combine ORDER BY and GROUP BY in a SELECT.
Any help would be apprechiated.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the output that I am expecting:

```
ID        Fruit        Category
_________________________________________
1          Apple        200 
10         Cranberries  200 
2          Pear         200 
3          Banana       300
8          Jackfruit    300
5          Mango        300
4          Peach        300
7          Cucomber     600
9          Salad        600 
6          Tomato       600
```

Comment: If you're talking about combining all of the rows for each category into a single row, you really ought not to do that in SQL. Otherwise, why is just `ORDER`ing by Category and then by Fruit not adequate?

Comment: can you show the output which you expecting?

Comment: Post edited with expected output

Comment: Yep. This is just using multiple columns for `ORDER`ing. `GROUP BY` is a mechanism that *reduces* the number of rows in a result set by computing aggregates (such as `SUM` or `MAX`, among others)

Answer (score 7):

```
select* from table_name order by category asc, fruit
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.

```
select* from table_name order by column_name asc // use your column name
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The trouble is that there are two columns that should be used in the ordering, not just one.  Also, the column names (but not the table name!) are given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated, no GROUP BY is required here.  GROUP BY is for aggregating rows. For example:

```
SELECT category, count(category) as [count] from myTable GROUP BY category
```

would give you something like this

```
category    count
--------    -----
200         3
300         4
600         3
```

You just want to order by two columns so all you need is

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY Fruit, Category
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY category ASC
```

Comment: you cant select * from group by used query.

Comment: I think the statement by @hkutluay is supposed to mean something like 'In SQL Server (and standard SQL), you have to list the non-aggregate columns in the select-list in the GROUP BY clause', unless you're using MySQL or some other conditions that usually don't apply.  Also, although you ensure the categories are listed in order, the names are not.  The GROUP BY clause actually is redundant; an ORDER BY clause is all that's needed.